# How to mask every third digit entered in input textbox. On click of a submit button, the original unmasked values must be displayed

Tags: angular, masking

Right now I am able to mask the digits only on blur.I need to mask them in the display as they are typed. On click of the submit button, the original entered values need to be displayed.
I have created it here: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnkvpt?file=src/app/app.component.ts](https://angular-gnkvpt.stackblitz.io)

https://angular-gnkvpt.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

You need use almost two variables, one to store the value and one to show it

```
  valueNoMask = '123456';
  value = MaskTransfor(this.valueNoMask, this.showMask);
```

Then, I go to split the `[(ngModel)]` in the way

```
<input #input
  type="text"
  name="value"
  [ngModel]="value"
  (ngModelChange)="change($event,input)"
/>
```

See that I pass to the function, futhermore the $event, the "HTML input" using a template reference variable -this `#input`-

This makes easy place the cursor not only at the end of the input else where it was.

But first I go to simplify your pipe. I like (as Angular makes) create a function that can be export and use in pipe

```
export function MaskTransfor(value: string, showMask: boolean): string {
  if (showMask)
    return [...value].map((x, index) => ((index + 1) % 3 ? x : '*')).join('');

  return value;
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'mask',
})
export class MaskPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string, showMask: boolean): string {
    return MaskTransfor(value, showMask);
  }
}
```

See that always we want to repeat "something" each time it's useful use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)

So you can use the function in the .ts in stead of need create an object MaskPipe.

The function change becomes like

```
  change(value: string, el: any) {
    //get where the cursor is
    const selectionStart = el.selectionStart;

    //find the parts equals the "value" -the actual value of the input
    //and this.value, the value "before". So, imagine 
    //this.value="12345" (
    //and value="123a45"
    //I want get three elements: 123, a, 45

    let end = 0;
    let start = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      if (value.slice(0, i) == this.value.slice(0, i)) start = i;
      if (value.slice(-i) == this.value.slice(-i)) end = -i;
    }

    
    if (end == 0 || start == 0) //if I changed at first or at end
      this.valueNoMask = this.valueNoMask.slice(0, start) + value.slice(start);
    else //else
      this.valueNoMask =
        this.valueNoMask.slice(0, start) +
        value.slice(start, end) +
        this.valueNoMask.slice(end);

    //equal the value to the value transform
    this.value = MaskTransfor(this.valueNoMask, this.showMask);
    
    //place the cursor in the position
    el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = selectionStart;
  }
```

You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s4h5mp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)